# theme div on user register / user login form

Tags: forms, drupal, registration

where is this nested div construction defined, that the user-login form doesnt has:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass-pass1 password-parent">
<div>
  <input>Password Input</input>
  <div>Password Strength</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input>Password Confirm</input>
</div>
```

i have looked in form.inc, the user-module folder but no luck. as stated, the user-login form is printed plain without any nesting like this, so where is this determination done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is added with js. Look into `ROOT/modules/user/user.js` for the code.